# How to download multi files in c#

Tags: c#, file, download

i won't to download multi files at this same time using c#, but i don't know how.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried to do thus far?  Have you 'downloaded' single files?  Can you give us an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please read tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I have code:
            HttpWebRequest request;

            HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try
            {

                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Link);

                //MessageBox.Show(Link);

                //request.Timeout = 10000;

                request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();



                //Write to disk

Comment: FileStream fs = new FileStream(Nazwa, FileMode.Create);

                byte[] read = new byte[256];

                int count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
                while (count > 0)
                {

                    fs.Write(read, 0, count);

                    count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
                    UpdateProgress(fs.Length, response.ContentLength);
                }

                //Close everything

                fs.Close();

                s.Close();

                response.Close();

Comment: , but when I start download 3 files at this same time, my program start downloading 2 files, and 3th file isn't download and i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://test.com/file1"), "C:/Localfile1");
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://test.com/file2"), "C:/Localfile2");
```

Comment: Jap, but when I try download 3 files at this same time, files aren't downloading at this same time, but this download each file in turn

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y.aspx for setting the maximum number of connections.

Comment: is it possible that you need to create multiple WebClients in your example? When I try something along this line, it tells me that WebClient cannot use parallel I/O... Or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to serve multiple download files on an asp.net post back, I've had alot of success zipping the files together on the fly, and streaming the result as the response.

edit -

This does not seems like what your trying to do, sorry.